# an error occurred during an attempt to establish a connection to the external data source

Tags: sharepoint-2013, powerpivot, bism

I have one Tabular SSAS project & I have deployed it on SQL Server Analysis Service 2012.

Then I have created a BISM connection to that deployed project as in following way.

[image]

Then I have created one PowerPivot excel report out of that BISM workbook using its connection string & it is working correctly in Excel.

But when I upload it to the SharePoint, it give me following error while refreshing the Data from BISM workbook.[image]

this error is observed only when I open it on browser i.e. Excel Web Access.

but the same error is not observed when I refresh the report in Microsoft Excel 2013.

why is it giving error on only SharePoint i.e. Excel Services. due to this I am not able to change Slicer's either.

One of the solution I found was to use some Hot Fix of SQL Server. but I haven't tried this. Plz refer the below link [Hot Fix for SQl Service Pack 1 Update](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/87cb9708-2dd0-407a-8911-840c7c2dc752/an-error-occurred-during-an-attempt-to-establish-a-connection-to-the-external-data-source?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it not possible to refresh the workbook which uses BISM connection on Browser (Excel Web Access)?

Answer (score 0):

This refresh should be possible, assuming permissions are set up correctly. You should post ULS logs for the time period of the refresh.

Does this same thing happen if you do a scheduled refresh (and choose refresh now)?